# Cloning volume using Libvirt Python createXMLFrom causes End of file while reading data: Input/output error

Tags: python, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I am trying to clone a volume using:

```
libvirt_conn = libvirt.openAuth(<qemu_addr>, <auth>, 0)
pool = libvirt_conn.storagePoolLookupByName(<pool_name>)
original_volume = pool.storageVolLookupByName(<original_volume_name>)
new_volume_xml = <xml_string>
new_volume = pool.createXMLFrom(new_volume_xml, original_volume)
```

When I run this I get the following error:
`End of file while reading data: Input/output error`

When I try:

```
libvirt_conn = libvirt.openAuth(<qemu_addr>, <auth>, 0)
pool = libvirt_conn.storagePoolLookupByName(<pool_name>)
original_volume = pool.storageVolLookupByName(<original_volume_name>)
new_volume_xml = <xml_string>
try:
    new_volume = pool.createXMLFrom(new_volume_xml, original_volume)
except:
    <next libvirt command>
```

I get a `client socket is closed` error. I have tried editing `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` with:

```
min_workers = 5
max_workers = 20
log_level = 1
log_filters="1:libvirt 1:util 1:qemu"
log_outputs="1:file:/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log"
keepalive_interval = -1
```

When I restart libvirtd and tail `/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log` I don't see anything useful. My feeling is the socket is closing because the cloning of the volume takes a longtime, but I am not sure how to keep the libvirt/qemu socket open longer. Is this possible?

Comment: You could try `virsh vol-clone --pool $POOL --vol $ORIGVOLNAME $NEWVOLNAME` and see if that errors. If it does, it's probably a libvirt bug. Long running APIs should not cause the socket to close unless libvirtd goes unresponsive (which would be a bug).